# Minimum access required for Visual Studio 2010 on SharePoint

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, permissions, sharepoint, visual-studio

Hi we are trying to set up a SharePoint development environment for multiple developers on Windows 2008 server, we do not want to give the developers admin rights to the servers.

Does anyone know what the minimum rights need to be. Right now if they are not admins they receive this error when trying to create a new project. Although it does create the folder for the project it gets stuck on this error.

"This task requires the application to have elevated permissions"

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a answer to your question (I don't know if this will solve your issue but try to add them as [Farm Adminstrators](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/09/01/sharepoint-security-and-permission-system-overview/)), however a better thing to do is give the developers their own instance they are administrators of for development. Then when moving to integration and production servers the developers should only have normal user rights.

It may cost more in licensing now but it will cost you less in the long run in IT support of your integration and production servers.